# regular expression extract string after a colon in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I need to extract the string after the `:` in an example below:

`package:project.abc.def`

Where i would get `project.abc.def` as a result.

I am attempting this in bash and i believe i have a regular expression that will work `:([^:]*)$`.

In my bash script i have `package:project.abc.def` as a variable called `apk`. Now how do i assign the same variable the substring found with the regular expression?

Where the result from `package:project.abc.def` would be in the `apk` variable. And `package:project.abc.def` is initially in the `apk` variable?

Thanks!

Comment: This smells like automatic uninstall or disabling of android packages if I'm not wrong

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no need for a regex here, just a simple prefix substitution:

```
$ apk="package:project.abc.def"
$ apk=${apk##package:}
project.abc.def
```

The ## syntax is one of bash's parameters expansions. Instead of #, % can be used to trim the end. See [this section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) of the bash man page for the details.

Some alternatives:

```
$ apk=$(echo $apk | awk -F'package:' '{print $2}')
$ apk=$(echo $apk | sed 's/^package://')
$ apk=$(echo $apk | cut -d':' -f2)
```

Comment: It works perfectly but it would be great if you can add some explanation on `##` thing.

Comment: This did not immediately work for my usecase. I had to use `${apk#*:}` instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ string="package:project.abc.def"
$ apk=$(echo $string | sed 's/.*\://')
```

".*:" matches everything before and including ':' and then its removed from the string.

Answer (score 2):

Capture groups from regular expressions can be found in the `BASH_REMATCH` array.

```
[[ $str =~ :([^:]*)$ ]]
# 0 is the substring that matches the entire regex
# n > 1: the nth parenthesized group
apk=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```