# Bash replace substring after first colon

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to build a connection string that requires pulling 3 IP addresses from another config file. When I get those values, I need to replace the port on each. I plan to replace each port using simple Bash find and replace `${string/pattern/replacement}` but my problem is I'm stuck on the best way to parse the pattern out of the IP.

Here is what I have so far:

**myFile.config:**

```
ip.1=ip-ip-1-address:1234:5678
ip.2=ip-ip-2-address:1234:5678
ip.3=ip-ip-3-address:1234:5678
```

Copying some other simple process, I found I can pull the value of each IP like this:

```
IP1=`grep "ip.1=" /path/to/conf/myFile.config  | awk -F "=" '{print $2}'`
```

which gives me `ip.1=ip-ip-1-address:1234:5678`. However, I need to replace `1234:5678` with `6543` for example. I've been looking around and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569123/regular-expression-extract-string-after-a-colon-in-bash) awesome answer that detailed using Bash prefix substitution but that relies on knowing the parameter. for example, I would have to do it this way:

```
test=${ip1##ip-ip-1-address:}
```

which results in $test being `1234:5678`. That's fine but maybe I don't know the IP address as the parameter, so I'm back to considering regex unless there's a way for me to use `*` as the parameter or something, but I have been unsuccessful so far. For regex, I have tried a bunch such as `test=${ip1/(?<=:).*/}`.

Comment: Maybe `sed -i 's/:.*/:6543/' myFile.config`? It will replace all text starting with the first `:`  on each line of the file with `:6543`.

Comment: Can you elaborate @WiktorStribiżew. Is this instead of my grep?

Comment: Yes, instead of `grep`, since you say  you need to *replace*. `grep` is used to *extract*.

Comment: `while IFS="=:" read -r var ip n1 n2; do echo "$var $ip $n1 $n2"; done < file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `${ip1/(?<=:).*/}` you tried is an example of [string manipulation syntax](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) that does not support regex, only specific patterns.

You seem to want

```
x='ip.1=ip-ip-1-address:1234:5678'
echo "${x%%:*}:6543" # => ip.1=ip-ip-1-address:6543
```

The `${x%%:*}` takes the value of `x` and removes all chars from the end till the first `:` including it. `:6543` is added to the result of this manipulation using `"${x%%:*}:6543"`.

To extract that value, you may also use

```
awk '/^ip\.1=/{sub("^[^:]+:", "");print}' myFile.config
```

The `awk` command finds lines starting with `ip.1=` and then removes all text from the start till the first colon including the colon and only prints these values.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but I am not looking to modify the input file. I need to take values from it and then replace the port for another dependency, hence my attempt at grep and replace in my new variable.

Comment: @johnny_mac You may use `sed` to modify strings, too. `ip="$(sed 's/:.*/:6543' file)"`. I re-wrote the answer with a string manipulation example.